# How to assign a classname to particular division after map in React js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I am mapping data inside a div, all i need  a border to div of "lab_add_to_cart_samp1" classname after clicking that division. I am confused how to make a division show active onclick even after mapping the data, there is an array of allabtest from API call

```
 <div className="lab_add_to_cart_samp">
                        {
                            allabtest.map((item, index) => {
                        return <div className="lab_add_to_cart_samp1" key={index}>
                                        <div className="lab_add_to_cart_samp_img1">
                                            <img src={REACT_APP_BASE_URL+"lab-test/download/"+item.id} />
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="lab_add_to_cart_test_desc">
                                            <p id="labtest_desc_txt1">{item.name}</p>
                                            <p id="labtest_desc_txt2">What it include :</p>
                                            <div className="labtest_desc1">
                                                <div className="labtest_desc_detail">
                                                    <ul>
                                                        <li>Platate</li>
                                                        <li>CBC</li>
                                                        <li>HB</li>
                                                    </ul>
                                                </div>

                                                <div>
                                                    <ul id="lab_test_detail">
                                                        <li>PCV</li>
                                                        <li>WBC/TLC</li>
                                                        <li>WBC/TLC</li>
                                                    </ul>
                                                </div>
                                                <div>
                                                    <ul id="lab_test_detail">
                                                        <li>DLC</li>
                                                        <li>RBC</li>
                                                        <li>ESR</li>
                                                    </ul>
                                                </div>
                                                <div>
                                                    <ul id="lab_test_detail">
                                                        <li>Platelets</li>
                                                        <li>Reticilocytes</li>
                                                        <li>Blood Grouping Rh type</li>
                                                    </ul>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="lab_add_to_cart_price">
                                            <p>Rs. {item.price}</p>
                                            <div className="lab_add_to_cart_atc">
                                                <button onClick={()=>addtocart(item)}>
                                                    <p>Add to Cart</p>
                                                </button>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                
                            })
                        }

                    </div>
```

Comment: You will need an object to keep track of the active state. It could even be the `item` object itself in your `allabtest` array that you add a field like "in_cart" or "selected". Or it could be a completely separate object that uses your item IDs as keys

Comment: could you please show a little through code?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set `active` for multiple divs at the same time you can do it like this

```
const allabtest = [
  {id: 'one', name: 'one'},
  {id: 'two', name: 'two'},
  {id: 'three', name: 'three'},
]

function App() {
  const [activeCart, setActiveCart] = useState({});

  return (
    <div className="lab_add_to_cart_samp">
      {allabtest.map((item, index) => {
        return (
          <div
            className={
              activeCart[item.id] === true
                ? "lab_add_to_cart_samp1 active"
                : "lab_add_to_cart_samp1"
            }
            onClick={() =>
              setActiveCart({
                ...activeCart,
                [item.id]: !Boolean(activeCart[item.id])
              })
            }
            key={item.id}
          >
            <div>{item.name}</div>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

If you want to track only one div then

```
function App() {


const [activeCart, setActiveCart] = useState();

  return (
    <div className="lab_add_to_cart_samp">
      {allabtest.map((item, index) => {
        return (
          <div
            className={
              activeCart === item.id
                ? "lab_add_to_cart_samp1 active"
                : "lab_add_to_cart_samp1"
            }
            onClick={() => setActiveCart(item.id)}
            key={item.id}
          >
            {/* Rest of your stuffs */}
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```